# Randomly determine whether a shape is filled or unfilled

Tags: java, random, shapes

I am trying to create a randomShape() method that instantiates and returns a random Shape object. I have all that figured out for the most part my issue is in my support method called getFilledUnfilled(). This support method needs to randomly determine whether a shape is filled/unfilled. Attached below is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Shape {

//enumerated constants
public static enum Shapes {OVAL, CIRCLE, RECTANGLE, SQUARE}

//instance data variables
protected Color color;
protected boolean isFilled;
protected int width;

//class method
public static Shape randomShape(){
    Shape s = new Shape();
    s.getRandomShapeObject();
    return s;
}//end randomShape()

//service method (blank, to be overridden by subclasses)
public void draw(Graphics g, int x, int y){

}//end draw()

//support methods

private void getRandomShapeObject(){
    ArrayList<Shapes>shapeChoice = new ArrayList<Shapes>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    int size = shapeChoice.size();
    shapeChoice.get(rand.nextInt(size));
}//end getRandomShapeObject()
```

Here is the method in question

```
private void getFilledUnfilled(){
    ArrayList<Shapes>shapeFillUnfill = new ArrayList<Shapes>();
    Random rand = new Random();


}
```

Comment: Won't calling [`Random#nextBoolean()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean--) do the trick?

Comment: That's originally what I was going to use. I would have two values that would need to be randomly generated. I can do that no problem, my issue becomes when they shapes need to get filled. would I so an if-statement or is there a better way to do it?